# after installed osb, can't run config.exe to create a domain in windows7

Tags: oracle, weblogic, soa, osb

I am a newbie to weblogic and currently trying to learn it. I have installed weblogic 11.1.1.5.0, Oracle XE, and also create a schema. However, when I installed osb, I can't run config.exe (directory: `C:\oracle\Middleware\home_11gR1\wlserver_10.3\common\bin` ) to create a domain. my computer is Windows7 64bit. I try to run `config.exe` as Administrator but no response.

Also, in the Start Menu, when I click the shortcut of config.exe or uninstall in the Oracle OSB 11g - Home1 folder, it just say I don't have access permissions.

when I installed SOA, I alse met the same problem like OSB.  I have installed these software in other PC which run windows XP, and there is no problem happen!

Here is the software I need to install

- WebLogic 11.1.1.5.0
- Oracle XE
- soa 11.1.1.3.0
- osb 11.1.1.3.0

So anyone can help?
Thanks in advance.

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Do you have admin rights? If so can you try right clicking and choosing "run as administrator"?

Answer (score 0):

Run config.cmd from \wlserver_10.3\common\bin.

If it does not work, it should display an error to point you why.